# as3: Mute button and volume slider on one sound channel

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs6

I have truly exhausted all my knowledge on this problem so I hope that my peers will be able to help me?

I am building a audio mixer that has five tracks with a volume slider and mute button per track. The reason for a mute button as opposed to a start/stop button per track is so that all the samples will be in sync regardless of when a sample is introduced.
The app has global start, stop and pause buttons which all function normally but I cannot get the volume slider and mute button to work in tandem on an individual sound channel.
The volume slider and the mute button will both work if I comment out the other function but when both are in play then only the volume slider works.
I'm guessing that there is a conflict because I have two separate variables using the soundTransform object/class but maybe you can shed some light on this conundrum?
Here is my code for one track... Any help appricated.

```
var mySound1:Sound1 = new Sound1();
var myChannel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var volumeAdjust1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
volumeAdjust1.volume = 0;

mute_btn1.stop();
mute_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,togglemute_btn1);

var Mute1:Boolean = false;

function togglemute_btn1(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if (Mute1)
    {
        mute_btn1.gotoAndStop(1);
        volumeAdjust1.volume = 1;
        myChannel1.soundTransform = volumeAdjust1;
        Mute1 = false;
    }
    else
    {
        mute_btn1.gotoAndStop(2)
        volumeAdjust1.volume = 0;
        myChannel1.soundTransform = volumeAdjust1;
        Mute1 = true;
    }

}

/*if the section below is commented out then the mute_btn1 works fine
otherwise the volume slider functions are dominent*/
var dragging1:Boolean = false;
var mySliderLength1:uint = 300;
var boundingBox1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,mySliderLength1);
slider_mc1.knob_mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragKnob1);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseKnob1);
slider_mc1.knob_mc1.buttonMode = true;

function dragKnob1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    slider_mc1.knob_mc1.startDrag(false, boundingBox1);
    dragging1 = true;
    slider_mc1.knob_mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, adjustVolume1);
}

function releaseKnob1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    if (dragging1)
    {
        slider_mc1.knob_mc1.stopDrag();
        dragging1 = false;
    }
}

function adjustVolume1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    var myVolume1:Number = slider_mc1.knob_mc1.y / mySliderLength1;
    var myTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(myVolume1);

    if (myChannel1!=null)
    {
        myChannel1.soundTransform = myTransform1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your `Mute1` variable in that listener of yours, and if muted, then volume=0, otherwise volume is calculated. And indeed, do remove your enter frame listener at the point of `stopDrag()` call.

```
function dragKnob1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    slider_mc1.knob_mc1.startDrag(false, boundingBox1);
    dragging1 = true;
    slider_mc1.knob_mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, adjustVolume1);
}

function releaseKnob1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    if (dragging1)
    {
        slider_mc1.knob_mc1.stopDrag();
        dragging1 = false;
        slider_mc1.knob_mc1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, adjustVolume1);
        // ^ this line added
    }
}

function adjustVolume1(myEvent:Event):void
{
    if (Mute1) return;
    // ^ and this line added
    var myVolume1:Number = slider_mc1.knob_mc1.y / mySliderLength1;
    var myTransform1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(myVolume1);

    if (myChannel1!=null)
    {
        myChannel1.soundTransform = myTransform1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vesper, both of your lines of code actually worked independently of each other but I have left both of them in as I can see where the adjust volume function might get confused if the mute button is active.

Comment: Having played around with it I figured out that if I left out the line: if(Mute1) return; . When I move the slider it automatically unmuted even though the mute_btn1 state would still be displayed as on so that was very helpful. 
The only issue I have now is that when I unmute the track it returns at full volume instead of the volume previously assigned by the slider!

Comment: This means you have to resort to slider position in unmute portion instead of setting that volume to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is you keep adding the Enter_Frame listener every time the mouse is clicked but it never gets removed.  So even after you let go of the knob the adjustVolume1 function is still getting called (which messes up anything the mute function call is doing on the frame after the mute toggle function is called).

So how I think I would deal with this given the current state is move the Enter_Frame listener addition outside of the dragKnob function and in the adjustVolume1 handler just check if dragging1 is true otherwise just return.

```
slider_mc1.knob_mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, adjustVolume1);

function dragKnob1(myEvent:Event):void
{
...
}

function adjustVolume1(myEvent:Event):void
{
   if(!dragging1)
       return;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort shaun but I could not get your adjustment to work but you did educate me to the fact that once I call an event it may need to be released again before another event can be carried out successfully.
As a note on that, I am actually developing the app for an android device so if I changed all my events to TouchEvent instead of MouseEvents might that improve some functionality of the app.